# Apache2 - Virtualhost shows content of another virtualhost

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I have Apache2 server running on Debian 9. And I have 2 virtualhost configs in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` folder.

First:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

<Directory "/srv/">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv">
        Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName domain.sk
       ServerAlias dev.domain.sk
       DocumentRoot /srv/domain.sk/!www
       <Directory /srv/domain.sk/!www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Second:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

<Directory "/home/test/">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName domain.sk
       ServerAlias test.dev.domain.sk
       DocumentRoot /home/test/domain.sk/!www
       <Directory /home/test/domain.sk/!www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is that if I go to `dev.domain.sk` it is **ok**, but if I go to `test.dev.domain.sk` it will show content of `dev.domain.sk` and **not** content of `test.dev.domain.sk`. If I disable first virtualhost config then I see content of `test.dev.domain.sk`, so it looks like `dev.domain.sk` "override" that `test.dev.domain.sk`, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `ServerName` directive twice with the same name. `ServerName` should be unique to each virtual host. You don't need `ServerAlias` in your example. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName dev.domain.sk
       DocumentRoot /srv/domain.sk/!www
       <Directory /srv/domain.sk/!www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test.dev.domain.sk
       DocumentRoot /home/test/domain.sk/!www
       <Directory /home/test/domain.sk/!www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```